# VTiger User Incoming Mail System Error (Failure)

Tags: gmail, vtiger

I am setting up a VTiger 5.4 installation and when configuring my user incoming mail to gmail, i get a red "System Error (Failure)" message when attempting to save the new mail account. Am new to Vtiger so, pretty much no idea where to start!

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In the Mail Manager module?  Click on Settings. Use the 'Select Organization Type' selector and choose Gmail. It should configure most of your settings.